# Which redirect URI should I use for my iOS Google OAuth response?

Tags: objective-c, ios, oauth, uri, gdata

I'm using a webview to display the Google login URL, and according to this page (https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2InstalledApp#choosingredirecturi),
there are two choice for a redirect callback. Which should I chose? Does iOS listen for responses to localhost? If so, how to I retrieve them?